# How to change resolution in ready! API 1.6.0?

Tags: soapui, ready-api

When I change resolution of my monitor, it increases resolution of ready API but resolutions for other apps gets messed up.
I tried increasing font size as well but that did not help much.
Please let me know if there is any other way to change resolution for only Ready API software.

I am facing one more issue where Ready API is working very slowly. I followed the steps to improve memory usage of the tool but that did not help much. Please let me know if someone has figured out any solutions for that as well.

I tried using the latest version 1.9.0 as well. Latest version is more slower than 1.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Can try the below solution from [here](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/SoapUI-5-2-1-adapting-the-UI-to-monitor-resolution-2880x1620/m-p/127163/highlight/true#M21843):

> Right click on SoapUI icon -> Properties - > Compatibility Tab - check Disable display scaling on high DPI settings

It is mentioned above `SoapUI Icon`. You can use the same for `Ready API`

And you may report the issue about slowness of ReadyAPI product to the SmartBear support team.